# Mosquitto broker not validating username and password sent by the publisher

Tags: client, server, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I have set " allow_anonymous " to false in the configuration file and have created a new password file using the mosquitto_passwd utility, but still the client is able to connect through any username and password.

what should i do ?

Comment: Update the question with the start of the output when you start mosquitto and the content of your config file

Comment: issue resolved we were correcting the wrong file and did not upload the config file after editing

Comment: we didn't know that u have to upload the new configuration file every time while running mosquitto

Answer (score 0):

`password_file` MUST not be empty. Or password is not required. Maybe can help you